# Script to get vmusage takes way too long and returns empty file

Tags: powershell, vmware

I have a script that used to work perfectly in our old domain.  It pulls the last vm usage info on our vmware users.  Since we switched to a new domain, I updated the ou line and now the script TAKES FOR EVER (like over an hour)  and then winds up erring out at the Export-CSV command.  I have the SqlServer module installed and am running with my privileged account that has access to our server and all accounts and persistent disks.

```
Export-CSV : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.
At \\.\Get-LastVmUsage2.ps1:88 char:13
+ $CSVArray | Export-CSV $Filename -Append -force
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

So tried removing $Filename variable and put in the full path

```
$CSVArray | Export-CSV -Path c:\temp\lastlogintime.csv -Append -force
```

Still takes an astronomically long time.  Could someone help me figure out why its taking so long and why it leaves the file empty?  I'm super new to programming and learning this all on my own.  Full script below with identifying info removed

```
Param (
    [string]$Filename,
    [int]$InactiveDays
)

try {
    Import-Module VMWare.PowerCli
    Write-Host "Imported VMware PowerCLI"
}

catch {
    Write-Host "Unable to import VMware module, please install it by running 'Install-Module Vmware.PowerCLI -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber'" -ForegroundColor Red
    Break
}

Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false
Connect-VIServer -Server icon-vc.iconid

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

if(!$InactiveDays){
    $InactiveDays = 45
}

if(!$Filename){
    $SaveDialog = New-Object -Typename System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $SaveDialog.Filter = "CSV File (*.csv) | *.csv"
    $Result = $SaveDialog.ShowDialog()
    if($Result.value__ -ne 1){
        Exit
    } 

    $Filename = $SaveDialog.Filename
}

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter 'Enabled -eq $True' -SearchBase "OU=Virtual,OU=Computers-Internal,DC=Domain,DC=Com"

class CsvRow {
  [object] ${ComputerName}
  [object] ${LastUser}
  [object] ${LastLogon}
  [object] ${Inactive}
}

$CSVArray = @()
$Today = Get-Date

foreach($Computer in $Computers){
    
    $Entry = New-Object CsvRow
    
    Try{
        $Data = Get-ChildItem "\\$($computer.Name)\d$\Users" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property Name, LastWriteTime -First 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        if($Data.LastWriteTime.AddDays($InactiveDays) -lt $Today){
            $Entry.Inactive = "True"
        } else {
            $Entry.Inactive = "False"
        }
    } catch {
        $Data = @{"Name"="";"LastWriteTime"=""}
    }

    $Entry.ComputerName = $Computer.Name
    $Entry.LastUser = $Data.Name
    $Entry.LastLogon = $Data.LastWriteTime
    $CSVArray += $Entry
}

$CSVArray | Export-CSV -Path c:\temp\lastlogintime.csv -Append -force
```

Comment: Why are you using PowerCLI, when you just connect a VIServer and then do nothing more with PowerCLI?

Comment: @Evilcat I'm not a sys admin. I didn't write this I just inherited it from our previous admin. All I really know how to do is edit the variables and file paths.

Answer (score 0):

A big timeloss is the way you expand your array.
This creates a new empty Array:

```
$CSVArray = @()
```

Inside your loop you keep adding to that array:

```
$CSVArray += $Entry
```

Because an array has a fixed size by design, powershell copies the entire array to a new array with an index greater by 1 compared to the old array.
And since you are doing this inside a loop, it does this for each loop, and it keeps getting slower each time.
if you have to add to an array, use a linked list:

```
# declaration
$CSVArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# Adding Entry to List
[void]$CSVArray.Add($Entry)
```

The .Add() method returns the current Count of the List.
To suppress this, is use [void] infront of the command.
This can save valueable time compared to the powershell CmdLet Out-Null,
especially in a big loop.
Here is a piece of code that shows the difference in executiontime:

```
$ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Array = @()

Measure-Command -Expression { 0..10000 | % { [void]$ArrayList.Add($_) } } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalMilliseconds |
    ForEach-Object { "ArrayList with [void] finished in:`t`t`t$($_) ms" }

Measure-Command -Expression { 0..10000 | % { $ArrayList.Add($_) | Out-Null } } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalMilliseconds |
    ForEach-Object { "ArrayList piped to Out-Null finished in:`t$($_) ms" }

Measure-Command -Expression { 0..10000 | % { $Array += $_ } } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalMilliseconds |
    ForEach-Object { "Array expanding with += finished in:`t`t$($_) ms" }
```

*ArrayList with [void] finished in:               48.0285 ms

ArrayList piped to Out-Null finished in:   274.6679 ms

Array expanding with += finished in:      1766.2551 ms*

#### EDIT

Do not Import all of VmWare.PowerCli.
The import is rather slow, instead execute each PowerCLI command that you use in the script in a new clean shell.
Afterwards run

```
Get-Module Vmware*
```

to see witch modules were auto imported and are realy needed.
Then import only those Modules at the start of your script:

```
Import-Module VmWare.Vim.Core,VmWare.Vim.Sdk,VMWare.WHATEVER...
```